# React-router + redux: Abort active transition when another transition is called

Tags: react-router

I've looking around and testing for a way to block current transition from one page to another when a third page is called during the loading of the second. The example is this:

I have a menu with three Links (A, B, C), and I'm in the page that corresponds to Link A.

I click on the Link B and react sends the request to the server.

Before the page from Link B is returned, I click the Link C.

The page C loads before the page B, but when the page B returns, the page B is loaded.

Is there a way to tell react to ignore the current active transition? Ignore the response from Link B?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of implementation details, but I'll give one real world example: I handle this by liberally taking advantage of the bluebird promise library, which implements [cancellation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancel.html). Loading "Page B" would do (roughly) something like this:

```
const pageRequests = {};

function loadPageB() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    pageRequests.pageB = makeAsyncRequest('pageB')
      .then((res) => dispatch({type: 'LOAD_PAGE', content: res})
      .finally(() => {
        delete pageRequests['pageB'];
      });
  };
}

function cancelLoad(page) {
  pageRequests[page].cancel();
}
```

You'd call `cancelLoad` to abort loading a page, which will cancel the request (note that the function that generates the page load promise will need to support cancellation!).

Alternatively, if you don't want to tangle with promise cancellation you can also just store a flag indicating that you no longer wish to see the results for that page. That flag would get reset every time you initiate a request to load the page.